# Ford Fiesta check engine light

Tags: engine, warning-light

Hi my Ford Fiesta (automatic) has the check engine light showing. What does it mean as it’s not very clear when I research it.

My car does have a parasitic drain on the battery which I was told by a garage was to do with the body control module however they just did a system update and told me to come back if further problems.

Comment: You need to have the codes read to know what the CEL means.

Answer (score 1):

When the warning light is on, a trouble code is stored in the computer. There are well over 800 possible trouble codes so it's impossible for us to guess which one is stored in your computer. You'll have to buy a code reader or get your car to an auto parts store that reads codes for free or get it to a shop See [this post](https://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/check-engine-light-on-part-i/) on trouble codes